# SSAS not import data from SQL Server for GeoLocation

Tags: sql-server, ssas, cube, dimension

I have a SQL Server table with GeoLocation.

[image]

I import data to SSAS and make a cube, but when I create a dimension, there is no data in GeoLocation, the column is empty.

Can anybody answer me what is wrong? I have all date but no GeoLocation:

[image]

Thanks for help.

Comment: I have to ask it... Was GEO Location added after your other fields? If so, did you process the Dimension?

Comment: I add whole dimension from my table in SQL, it is added together with other, thats why I dont now why GeoLocation is empty

Comment: What is the datatype of GeoLocation?

Comment: GeoLocation is type geography.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the column to string.

Comment: I string it, and add GeoLocation2 to dimension, and i see it, but i dont understand why i cant see GeoLocation like geography??

Can I do the raports in SSRS with datatype nvarchar??

thx for help

Comment: I've not used geolocation in cubes before,but know that  SSAs doesn't like weird data types in dimensions